# What is the impact of the lazy flag in BlocProvider?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to understand what impact does the lazy flag have. And what are the considerations for setting it as true or false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it is true, the Bloc or Cubit should be created lazily, that means, it is not created by the provider until the first request of accessing the Bloc such as `context.read<MyBloc>`

You can set lazy true when initializing is costly, or it has some side effects, i.e a Restful API called (it is not needed to call the API until user do some action and lazily created the Bloc) on otherside you can set lazy as false for prefetching data

Comment: `lazy` *is* true [by default](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider/lazy.html).

Comment: Thanks, I read some more online, and lazy seems to define the behavior of how our code works. Lazy loading means creating something only once it is needed (hence the term lazy), whereas the opposite would be to have things ready at the start itself. This may sound very obvious to those who are experienced but it wasn't so obvious for a newbie like me. Which one to use depends on the kind of loading you want your application to perform - slow at the start and then smooth or faster initial load followed by slow updates.

Answer (score 5):

As the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider-class.html) say:

> By default, `Create` is called only when the instance is accessed. To
> override this behavior, set `lazy` to false.

Therefore, the impact is when `Create` will be called, and thus when (if *at all*) your your BLoC is created. By default, `lazy` is `true`, so if you never access the instance of the BLoC, it will not be created. Conversely, when `lazy` is `false`, the `Create` method will be called instantly when the Widget is built.

Behind the scenes, the value is passed to the underlying [InheritedProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/InheritedProvider-class.html).